# Folders/files structure for nuxt query string parameters

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, nuxt.js, vue-router

How should the files and folders be structured so that they would use URL query string parameters instead of regular parameters?

Example:

URL parameters:

Folder structure:

```
pages/
---|comments/
------|_id.vue
```

This structure results in this route:

```
pages/comments/page/1
```

How do the folders/files need to be structured so that my route is like the one below?

URL query string parameters:

```
pages/comments?page=1
```

Comment: I think url query isn't a part of routing so you just go with `/pages/comments` route and then access the query later in component e.g. `this.$router.query.page`. See related https://nuxtjs.org/guide/routing#locally-accessing-route-params.

Comment: When page is set using this.$router.query.page on created() hook it is not displayed in the URL in the browser but it is attached to $router object.

Comment: For navigate you should use `<router-link :to='/pages/comments?page=1'>` or `<router-link :to='{ name: 'commentName', query: { page: 1 } }'>` or `this.$router.push('/pages/comments?page=1')` or ...

Comment: Yeah for sure but  I am trying to set up initial page load parameters. I am having some amount of success using 

     `this.$router.push({path: this.$route.path,query: { page: this.currentPage }})`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The conclusion I came to:

- For index page don't query string parameter for the first page on the initial load.
- Watch for query string changes using:
  `watch: { '$route.query': '$fetch' }` (this will run the fetch method on every single page change or anything else that you have in your query string)
- Since fetch() is run on every single page change you will need to include query string parameters in your requests using `this.$route.query.page` (page in my case)
- You will also need to make sure that your page is always set to some number even when you are on your index page and no query parameters are applied:

  ```
  if (this.$route.query.page) {
     this.currentPage = this.$route.query.page
  } else {
  this.currentPage = 1
  }
  ```

Also if you need to route to a page with parameters attached use:
`this.$router.push({path: this.$route.path,query: { page: 1}})`

Using nuxt-link
`<nuxt-link :to="{ name: '/', params: { page: 1 }}"></nuxt-link>`: